# Tapkey Token Exchange returns access token for invalid user

Tags: authentication, token, tapkey

regarding tapkey token exchange flow: when exchanging a jwt token for an access token through https://login.tapkey.com/connect/token api, I get an access token response, even the user does not exist.

My jwt token contains of the following: Header:

```
{
  "alg": "RS256"
}
```

Payload:

```
{
  "algorithm": "RS256",
  "aud": "local",
  "iat": 1633339589,
  "exp": 1633343189,
  "iss": "tapkey",
  "sub": "NOT_EXISTING_USER_ID"
}
```

this raises the following questions:

1. when I create an IdentityProviderUser I get in return an `id` and an `ipUserId`.
   Should the jwt-token's `"sub"` be the returned `id` or should `"sub"` be the returned `ipUserId`?
   In both cases I am able to retrieve an access token, because regardless what I define in `"sub"` an access token is exchanged.
2. what happens when mobile tries to login with a not existing user's access token?

Answer (score 0):

For the token exchange itself it does not matter if the user already exists or not. It just validates your signed token and exchanges it with a token for the tapkey system.

The subject of your jwt token should be *your* assigned userId (= ipUserId) which also was/will be used to create the user:
https://developers.tapkey.io/api/ip_users/#create-identity-provider-user

Ad 2:
By default when a mobile tries to login in the tapkey mobile sdk with a token with an id, which was not created yet, will cause an error.